# Add .git/config to another Git repository

Tags: git

I've got a repository which contains most of my application settings. I'd like to add `.git/config` from a different repo and replace it with a symlink in the original repo, but Git complains:

```
error: Invalid path '[...]/.git/config'
error: unable to add [...]/.git/config to index
fatal: adding files failed
```

Note: I'm not trying to add this to the root directory of the settings repo, but in a subdirectory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A symbolic link won't work here. You can set the GIT_CONFIG environment variable to point to your config file instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just put those settings in your global `.gitconfig` so it will apply to all repositories on your system – and remove them from the local `.git/config` so they won’t override your changes in `.gitconfig` as your preferences change and you update that.

Comment: There's also a system-wide config in `$(prefix)/etc/gitconfig`.

Comment: The settings I'm most interested in backing up are the remotes and branches - I don't want those in my global configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `git submodule`? It does sounds like its what you're looking for: a project that contains other projects.